# Chrome extension is missing files after auto-update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension on the Chrome Web Store that I update regularly. Every now and then, it looks like Chrome messes up when deploying the update and skips over a file.

Here's what I know:

1. The file is always the same one: `js/secret.js` which is a .gitignored file that I temporarily include so `git archive` won't pass over it when creating the ZIP.
2. When I notice this file is missing after the latest update, I can go to chrome://extensions and toggle the extension off/on and then the file will appear. **I didn't have to do anything else**
3. This issue does not happen all the time.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to prevent this? I doubt it's a problem with Chrome but I'm also not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks I'll submit an issue!